# Is it possible to make this button send the file to a discord webhook or google drive or something?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, discord

```
<form action="/action_page.php">Birb's Encrypted File Sharing<br />"No logs, No Nonsense<br /><br /><br /><br /><input id="myFile" name="filename" type="file" /><br /><input id="myFile" name="filename" type="file" /><br /><input id="myFile" name="filename" type="file" /><br /><input
    id="myFile" name="filename" type="file" /><br /><input id="myFile" name="filename" type="file" /><br /><input id="myFile" name="filename" type="file" /><br /><br /> <input type="submit" /><br /><br />Link:</form>
```

**THATS THE CODE!!**

***I was wondering when someone uploads files and clicks submit if it can send the file to a discord webhook or google drive folder or somewhere else. I also wanted to know if it could be uploaded to a password protected website.onion/index link***

Comment: You can convert to base64 and send to some api in a server side language.

Comment: Please strip unnecessary vulgarities out of your codebase before sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way [source: https://github.com/Iku/Google-Forms-to-Discord]

Create a Google Form https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/

Make the form however you'd like.

Go to the Script editor.

paste this script:
https://github.com/Iku/Google-Forms-to-Discord/blob/master/google%20script.js

Open Discord and make a channel where you'd like the responses to be sent.

Create a webhook and copy the URL. Replace WEBHOOKURL at the top of the script with the URL you copied.

Add a trigger by selecting Current project's triggers in the Edit menu, and creating a new trigger using the settings given below.